# Enabling multisampling in Irrlicht?

Tags: opengl, c++, irrlicht, antialiasing

I'm working on a little game that uses Irrlicht. I'm pretty new to Irrlicht and I was wondering how I could enable multisampling. The device driver is `EDT_OPENGL` initiated as such:

```
IrrlichtDevice *device = createDevice(video::EDT_OPENGL,
                                        core::dimension2d<u32>(800, 700),
                                        16,
                                        NO);
```

How do I enable multisampling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution, but you'll need to call **createDeviceEx** instead of the current function.

You'll have to pass a **SIrrlichtCreationParameters** structure to the above function, with the AntiAlias member set to *true* (or another value ? It seems that the variable is an unsigned integer, and not a bool, never noticed that). Of course you'll have to define some other structure members in order to have the same IrrlichtDevice as the one in your question. ;)

Here's a piece of code if you prefer : (warning : I've not used Irrlicht since 1 year now)

```
SIrrlichtCreationParameters params = SIrrlichtCreationParameters();
params.AntiAlias = true;
params.DriverType = video::EDT_OPENGL;
params.WindowSize = core::dimension2d<u32>(800, 700);
IrrlichtDevice *device = createDeviceEx(params);
```

See [here](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/structirr_1_1_s_irrlicht_creation_parameters.html#a50602e6ae0cc3d79ca7df0aa8114e75a) for (unfortunately not much) information. (the Irrlicht doc is in fact not very helpful, unfortunately)

Hope this helps, good night ! :-)

Comment: I think a combination of your answer and user1201210's is correct.  It should be "params.AntiAlias = 8;" The higher, the better it seems.

Comment: The AntiAlias value is meant to be a u8 not a boolean. Valid values are powers of two, so 2, 4, 8, 16. The device usually falls back to the next highest number if you specify a factor that is too high. 1 is usually the same as 0, but it depends if the hardware has a special meaning for 1 as an AntiAlias value.

Answer (score 2):

Quick addendum to Minishlink's answer: `AntiAlias` is the number of samples to use in anti-aliasing. The following snippet comes from Irrlicht's COpenGLDriver.cpp.

```
// This value determines the number of samples used for antialiasing
// My experience is that 8 does not show a big
// improvement over 4, but 4 shows a big improvement
// over 2.
if(AntiAlias > 32)
    AntiAlias = 32;
```